# How to limit has_one association to a single record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am having trouble with retaining only a single record in a has_one relationship

**Example**

Categories and question

A question **belongs_to** a category, and a category **has_one** question

In reality as seen in a system i am building even though the has_one relationship exists, there comes a case where i have multiple questions that belong to a category.

Shouldn't the has_one relationship limit them to just one record? If not, then how can i make sure that i always keep one record?

**EDIT**

Please note that question model has a uniqueness rule on the ID of category and **STILL** i found cases of **multiple records** that point to same category ID.

How is that possible?

**EDIT 2**

Overview of the models

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :travel_time, :inverse_of => :event, dependent: :destroy
end

class TravelTime < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :event, :inverse_of => :travel_time
     validates_uniqueness_of :event_id, allow_nil: true 
end
```

**EDIT 3**

method in **event** model used to save the travel time record

```
def store_travel_times(body)
    travel_times = self.build_travel_time

    # get travel times
    ...

    if !travel_times.save
     logger.error "..."
    end
end
```

Query used to find the multiple records

```
 2017-05-04T13:39:15.277063 #50567] DEBUG -- :   TravelTime Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "travel_times".* FROM "travel_times" WHERE "travel_times"."event_id" = $1  [["event_id", 3105]]
```

Comment: please share your model, association and validation.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon please see updated post

Comment: your create action where you create columns?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon you mean the migration file?

Comment: Can u post a code where u see multiple records? I mean code, query and output?

Comment: nope, your controller where you create the records.

Comment: @AKovtunov added the sql query used

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon there is no controller action to create these records, this is a complex system, and the creation of the record happens in the event model. You can find the relevant code in the post above (edit 3)

Comment: can you share `build_travel_time`?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon build_travel_time is a built in function of a has_one relationship so there is nothing to share

Comment: ok, my bad. Just to confirm, do you have unique constraint on `event_id` at db level?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon no i dont and i am thinking thats the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, create db level constraint to check uniqueness of a column and avoid multiple records creation. You need to create a migration file with below code:

```
add_index :travel_times, :event_id, unique: true
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but make sure that your first argument is plural. In this case, should be `add_index :travel_times, :event_id, unique: true`. Also, that index is automatically created for the association when using resources, but it isn't unique by default, so you might need to run `drop_index :travel_times, :event_id` on the line before in your migration.

Comment: thanks for bringing that point up @boyd, almost 2.5 years ago when I had started rails.. (；・∀ ・)

Comment: Of course! Sorry that it's such a minor detail. Just thought it might help if someone newer is in search of your particular solution!