# has_one model association not enforcing 'one' in associated model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, rails-models

I have the following

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_one :physician

end
```

and

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user

end
```

Since a user can only have one physician, I was surprised that multiple physician records can be created with the same user id.

Why is this? And how to I prevent it?

Comment: Yeah, rails doesn't update one the record, it just uses the last one.  This answer uses a db level constraint... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43783347/how-to-limit-has-one-association-to-a-single-record

Comment: How are you creating physicians ?

Comment: @Maxence the idea is that every single user who signs up is automatically considered a Patient, and a small subset of those patients will be doctors in real life, and they can become a Physician. Suppose I am a doctor in real life and I sign up, then I become a User and a Patient, and once I apply inside the app, I become a Physician too. But the user "steve" can certainly only be *one* physician. I hope this makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `belongs_to` association does not in any way guarantee that the values are unique. It only stipulates that the association is stored in a foreign key on *this* models table and thus can only have a single value.

`has_one` doesn't actually provide any guarantees either. It just specifies that *this* table is referred to on the *other* table. If there are multiple matching rows on the other table it will chose the last.

If you want to enforce uniqueness per table you need a validation:

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
end
```

And a database index to [actually guarantee uniqueness on the database level](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations):

```
class AddUniqueIndexToPhysicians < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_index :physicians, :user_id, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Max! Random question. Why is the migration necessary? (I would have guessed the validation would have been enough)?

Comment: Because of race conditions. The linked article explains it far better than I can.

Comment: Took me a while, but just read the article. Great explanation

Comment: For some reason `ArgumentError: Index name 'index_physicians_on_user_id' on table 'physicians' already exists`. Perhaps `validates_uniqueness_of :user_id` alone is enough?

Answer (score 0):

`Physician` probably shouldn't have a `user_id` associated to it:

```
class User
  belongs_to :physician # has a physician_id column
end

class Physician
  has_many :users # has no mention of user_id in its schema
end
```

`belongs_to` is required by default for Rails 5 and later. If users can onboard without a physician and you need to disable this:

```
class User
  belongs_to :physician, optional: true 
end
```

And then later, validate the presence of `physician` only after some condition.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The idea is that every user who signs up will be a user, and some (who are doctors in real life) can apply to become a Physician. So 99% of users will not be a physician, but ~1% will be, and they'll also have a user account. E.g. Suppose I'm a doctor in real life and I sign up, I'll have a user account then apply to be  physician and get a Physician record. Presently the database doesn't stop me making multiple Physician records (but it should, and that's the part I'm having trouble with)